# Unable to install VIrtualbox 5 "libvpx1 missing" warning (even though it's installed)

Tags: virtualbox, dependencies

I'm unable to install `virtualbox 5.0_5.0.6-103037.deb`. I've followed the steps in [this article](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/solved-virtualbox-is-not-installing-in-ubuntu-1510-due-to-missing-dependency-libvpx1), so I've already installed the library by downloading it from there, but the Package installer keeps showing the warning that the dependency is missing:

[image]

**note:** I need to try this version of virtualbox because I'm stuck trying to install MAC OSX in a VM, and I've found a tutorial that works with this version, I've already tried the virtualbox available in Ubuntu Software Center and it doesn't work :/

**note2:** Ubuntu version 16.04

Comment: -1 If you want OS X, buy a Mac.

Comment: sorry I don't have money for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of installing the virtualbox package the GUI way, I used APT. From the directory where the `.deb` file is:

```
sudo apt install ./virtualbox-package-file-name.deb
```

And it worked perfectly.

Comment: Please could you clarify? You ran this command after installing "the lib", and then it succeeded? But what was "the lib" and how did you install that?

Comment: it is the one described above, libvpx1, I did installed using the link above on my question text, after that I did `sudo apt install ./virtualbox-package-file-name.deb` and it was fixed

Comment: Oh. So you followed the guide and it worked after all, the only difference was using APT instead of Gdebi?

Comment: Yes that's correct, because using gdebi it will always result in that screenshot attached, using APT solves my issue